# iOS error "dyld no valid entry point". How to resolve it?

Tags: ios, entry-point, dyld

When I run my application on simulator, I was struck with the following error.

"dyld no valid entry point iOS".

How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is resolved. I have added a framework dylib and removing some of those libs made the error vanish!

Hope this would help others in future.